# How to get time from a variable having both date & time?

Tags: php

I have a variable as:

```
$date_time = 2016-11-08T14:22:08.240Z
```

now how can i extract time in the format as `14:22` from the given variable.

Comment: `echo date('H:i', strtotime('2016-11-08T14:22:08.240Z'));`

Comment: echo date('H:i',strtotime($date_time));

Comment: You can at least search a bit.

Comment: not working.......giving time as 09:22

Comment: check - https://eval.in/674781

Comment: show us your error

Comment: Check timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the time_zone. To get the appropriate time . try below code:

```
 date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
 $date_time = '2016-11-08T14:22:08.240Z';
 echo date("H:i",strtotime($date_time));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `DateTime()`

```
$date_time = new DateTime( '2016-11-08T14:22:08.240Z', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) );
echo $date_time->format( 'H:i' );
```